# Assigining data from one file to other

Tags: sed, awk

I have a job to adding a row data in one file to another file having same id. Which program I can use do complete this job.

Input file1

```
481063384 PBPb
481063384 PBPb
481063384 LT_GEWL
481063384 lysozyme_like
481063384 SLT
481063384 emtA
481063406 Hsp33
481063406 Hsp33
481063406 COG1281
481063406 HSP33
```

Input file2

```
481063384 putative soluble lytic transglycosylase 
481063406 chaperonin HslO
```

Desired Output

```
481063384 putative soluble lytic transglycosylase PBPb
481063406 chaperonin Hsp33
```

Condition first I need to extract first line of the repeating number and I need to assign or add.
Please Help me.
I am thinking awk will be useful but I am not good at awk programming.

Comment: What's the pattern to get the 2nd column from the 1st file?  I see many lines with `481063384` and different 2nd column and don't understand why you print `PBPb`.

Comment: As You see many lines with 481063384(This is Accession no. of Protein), first I need to print first string of first 481063384 n discard other 481063384, I need to repeat same for each different Accession no. then I want to add the output to same Accession no. in other file. I think U understand my question by now @ fedorqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ if( $1 in a) next;a[$1]=$2;next}{$0=$0" "a[$1]}1' file1 file2
```

Comment: Nice; reparsing each line by assigning to `$0` can be avoided, though, by replacing `{$0=$0" "a[$1]}1` with `{print $0" "a[$1]}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join and if you want first line of each, use awk :

```
join file2 file1 | awk '{if(a!=$1) print}{a=$1}'
```

gives :

```
481063384 putative soluble lytic transglycosylase PBPb
481063406 chaperonin HslO Hsp33
```

Comment: Thank U this is also working but here it was ignoring those numbers not in file1. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "it was ignoring those numbers not in file1"

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{!seen[$1]++&&line[$1]=$2;next}$0=$0 FS line[$1]' file{1,2}
```

Comment: +1 for a more concise version of the accepted answer, but here, too, reparsing each line by assigning to `$0` can be avoided by replacing `$0=$0 FS line[$1]` with `{print $0 FS line[$1]}`.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks or `{print $0,line[$1]}` `;)`.